# pyautogui to detect the button change

Tags: python, pyautogui

pyautogui works well when using it to click on the buttons (of a software ) on the screen 
but is there any way to detect the change in button state, because when the first click is completed and the required task is accomplished then the button disappears and a new "yes" button appears and if the task is not accomplished then the "NO" button appears , the problem is , both buttons appear at the same x and y coordinates i mean either yes or no appears at that place , is there any way to find out if yes appeared or no appeared? and then clicking if yes appeared ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use image recognition technique in pyautogui package.
You can use locateOnScreen function of pyautogui. First you can screenshot and save yes and no button image. You crop the image tightly around the button.
And then save them into "yes.png", and "no.png" respectively.
And then,

```
btnYesButton = None
btnNoButton = None
while btnYesButton == None and btnNoButton == None:
    btnYesButton = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("yes.png")
    btnNoButton = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("no.png") 
if btnYesButton:
    tmpCenter = pyautogui.center(btnYesButton)
    pyautogui.click(tmpCenter)
```

Comment: thanks Metalgear , how fast is this method in your opinion? 
can it perform in a second or less?

Comment: No, it'll take at least 2 seconds as far as I know. It depends on screen resolution and image resolution

Comment: any  fast alternative to accomplish this ?